# Setup pull requests with git flow and azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, git-flow

I'm trying to setup a library project using DevOps. The branching strategy choosed is **git-flow** in order to have use git version and follow semver with releases and hotfixes.

So i tried was to **protect both develop and release branches** by activating pull requests.

Everything works fine unless a release is going to be closed. Here I see two problems:

1. In git-flow the system try to realign develop from master, but devops doesn't know this is git-flow and just merges release to master.
2. Develop branch is protected, so if i want to realign manually i should create a new pull request, from master to a feature branch in order to solve conflicts

I'm not sure about the correctnes of the implemented workflow. Is there a better way to accomplish this realignment?

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At present, azure devops is designed like this. Devops can only be one-to-one branch merge at the same time.The release branch cannot be merged into the master branch and into the develop branch at the same time.

> When the release is finished, the release branch is merged into master
>   and into develop too, to make sure that any changes made in the
>   release branch aren’t accidentally lost by new development.

This feature described in git flow cannot be implemented in azure Devops.

So, your understanding is correct, you can do it manually by your method, although this may be a bit inconvenient.