# Automatic merge into develop from release branch (develop needs PR)

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, pull-request

I'm trying to combine gitflow and PRs in AzureDevOps. So far I couldn't find any suitable solution. I will stay in manual git flow with PRs :). Is there any possibility to auto merge all commits that are commited into release branch into develop which is protected from direct commits? Or maybe automatic merge int develop after we merge to master? The idea is to automate as much as possible as it is in git flow but stay with PRs as well?

Note: This needs to be possible only in AzureDevOps.

I know that github is able to close PR when you do the git flow finish feature. Something similar is needed in AzureDevOps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to auto merge all commits that are commited
>   into release branch into develop which is protected from direct
>   commits? Or maybe automatic merge int develop after we merge to
>   master?

For this issue , I am afraid that this feature is not available in azure devops. At present, azure devops is designed like this: Devops can only be one-to-one branch merge ,can't automatically merge into the develop branch after merging into the master branch. The feature described in git flow cannot be automatically implemented in azure Devops. So，if you want to merge into the develop branch after merging into the master branch, you need to manually create a new pr,although this may be a bit inconvenient.

You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925676/setup-pull-requests-with-git-flow-and-azure-pipelines), the issue in this case is the same as yours.